# the returning pointer is garbage value in c

Tags: pointers, memory, allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char* findNumber(int arr_size, int* arr, int k);
char* findNumber(int arr_size, int* arr, int k) {
    char *result =malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
    int i;
    int flag = 1;

    for ( i = 0;i<arr_size;i++){
        if (*(arr+i)==k){
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    else if (flag = 0){
             *(result) = "YES";
         }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    int arr [3]= {1,2,3};
    int size = 3;
    int k = 3;
    char * a;
    a = findNumber(size,arr,k);
    printf(" %s",a);
    return 0 ;
}
```

In this code I'm trying to find a number in a given array and the result will be stored in character pointer pointing to array  and I will print the result from the main but I keep getting garbage value what is the wrong in my code ?

Comment: Please edit for readability. Punctution, capital letters and some newlines in prose. Indentation in code.

Comment: okay what is not obvious ?

Answer (score 1):

First, in order to do what you are describing, pass a pointer to the variable you wish to modify (in C++, you would pass by reference). In this case, the function would be something like:

```
void findNumber(int arr_size, int* arr, int k, char* result) {

// do something that modifies result

}
```

Second, this line is wrong:

```
else if (flag = 0){
```

this condition will always return `true`, and the `else` is misplaced.

Comment: the flag will be  0 if i found the number that is the only case

Comment: and i cant do this because i only got these variables i cant include another variable in the function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see 'Help' at the top right of the answer window to see how to format code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not getting any syntax error?
Check parenthesis near for loop
If is scoped inside the for loop and else if is out of it.
And jst do return "yes"; else return "no"

Answer (score -1):

i had a mistake in the if conditions and i didnt use the strcpy() thank you guys

Comment: You should not use `strcpy` because it's unsafe.

Comment: what should i use then ?

Comment: There are safer alternatives to `strcpy`. `strcpy` can cause a Buffer Overflow if the source buffer is larger than the destination buffer. `strncpy` is slightly safer.